# Firefox extension include script in main.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing an extension for firefox and having a problem including scripts into the main.js (background) file ...

In my case I would like to include for example jquery.js and config.js but I can't see how to do it properly.

In my chrome extension I just do that on the manifest file but I would like the equivalent in firefox.

Thank you for your help,
jdmry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import files you use [Components.utils.import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.import).

You will need a URL from which to import the file. Usually, this is either a resource:// or chrome:// URL.

Some examples of Mozilla supplied libraries:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm"); //File Utilities
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");   //Network utilities
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");  //Services
```

Some examples of loading from your own extension:

```
Components.utils.import("chrome://myExtensionModule/content/common.jsm");          //Common
Components.utils.import("chrome://myExtensionModule/content/classes.jsm");         //Classes
```

In order to load from your own extension, you will need to have the files in a folder that has been mapped to a chrome:// or resource:// URL within your chrome.manifest.  For example with the line:

```
content       myExtensionModule                             modules/
```

This does not need to be separate from the folder which you normally map for content, but it is common to keep JavaScript modules in a separate folder, just for organization. You do not need to have them use a .jsm extension, again just a convention. Using .js is just fine and may be desirable if you have other tools which auto-config based on a .js extension (e.g. an editor).

Significantly more information can be found in the documentation on MDN:

- [JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.import)
- [Using JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using)
- [Add-on SDK Tutorial: Creating Reusable Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Creating_Reusable_Modules)

Note that in Firefox code it is common for there to be a mapping to shorter variables to access some commonly used Firefox properties. Specifically, the following are often used:

```
const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
const Cu = Components.utils;
```

Usually these are defined in a much more abbreviated manner. They are explicitly stated above to make the mapping more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can I import just classic js code with this method like my config.js which contains only some vars and few helper functions without designing it as a module or a js object ?
And also I am not using a chrome.manifest at all ... Don't know what chrome as to do with all that (just have a package.json)

Comment: There really is not any difference (as code) between what is written as code within a module and your normal code.  However, they do run under different contexts and the module code does not have automatic access to your normally expected window and document objects. You can get access to them, but you have to code that, or pass them as arguments to the function you are calling. In anything you have as a module, you need to have a variable called EXPORTED_SYMBOLS which contains an array of the variables which are visible to code which imports it.

Comment: You appear to be using the Add-on SDK.  I added a link to a MDN tutorial on how to create reusable modules with the add-on SDK.

Comment: Yes I am using the addon sdk, I can create a module for my config for example but it is gonna be more complicated to do that with jquery...

Comment: There is no point to import jQuery - there is now window object or DOM to access in main.js. What are you actually trying to do?