# can you load external executable javascript from a firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Does anyone know if there is a way to load any external executable javascript from a firefox add-on extension?  I looked into scriptloader.loadSubScript, but it appears that it can only load from a local resource.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always xhr for a file, save the contents to disk, then use scriptloader.loadSubScript with an add-on

this would violate the AMO policies though, so you wouldn't be able to upload the add-on to http://addons.mozilla.org

Comment: Is there an alternative that would not violate the AMO policies?

Comment: @Erich: No, there is no alternative.  Your desire to load code that is not in the add-on release is inherently at odds with the security related policies at AMO. There is quite a bit in place to specifically prevent accidentally doing what you desire because running unknown code (sourced outside the add-on bundle) with extension-level privileges is inherently a security issue.

Answer (score 2):

As @erikvold already pointed out, doing so would be a security hazard AND it also violates AMO rules (because it is a security hazard).

Consider your server gets compromised, or there is a way to MITM the connection retrieving the remote script (TLS bugs anyone :p), or you sell your domain and the new owner decides to ship a script to collect credit card information straight from a user's hard disk...

However, it is possible to run a remote script in an unprivileged environment, much like it would run in a website.

- Create a [`Sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.Sandbox). The Sandbox should be unprivileged, e.g. pass an URL in your domain into the constructor.
- Retrieve your script, e.g. with XHR.
- [Evaluate your script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.evalInSandbox) in the Sandbox and pull out any data it might have generated for you.

This is essentially what tools like Greasemonkey (executing user scripts) do.

Creating and working with Sandboxes in a secure fashion is hard, and the Sandbox being unprivileged prohibits a lot of use cases, but maybe it will work for your stuff.

Comment: @Erich, Thanking somebody for answers on stackoverflow usually involves upvoting the answer (you can upvote more than one).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Components.utils.import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.import) .

**Example :**

const {Cc,Ci,Cu} = require("chrome");

Cu.import("url/path of the file");

**Note :**

js file which uses DOM objects like window, navigator, etc. will return error saying "window/navigator is undefined". This is simply because the main.js code does not have access to DOM.

Refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850601/firefox-extension-include-script-in-main-js-file) for more information.

Comment: I've tried this but I can't figure out how to get an external URL to work.  All the documents I read about it show either a chrome:// or resouce:// url that is referring to fles that already exist in the project.  Is it possible to grab a javascript file from a web site when the extension initializes?

Comment: This does not work for external Javascript, which is what the question asked.